# Maven deploy into SNAPSHOT repository with a different suffix

Tags: maven, deployment, snapshot, artifact, mvn-repo

I'd like to mvn deploy an artifact with the suffix -DEVELOP into the pre-defined snapshot repo, but maven decides to push it into the release repository. I guess it is due to naming policy, the artifact withouth -SNAPSHOT goes to the release repo.

But if I set the snapshot repo explicitly for this deploy job, I get a 400 Bad request error. Is it because the snapshop repo only permits artifacts with the snap suffix?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The simple thing is `-SNAPSHOT` means it's snapshot and uses the snapshot repository everything else is a release and uses the release repository. That's the definition in Maven. Please show the output of the error?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes I figured this out. The question is: can I change this behavior, can I push images with suffixes apart from -SNAPSHOT into the snapshot repository?

Comment: Why? A SNAPSHOT means something which is under development a release is a fixed immutable state... What is the problem with `-SNAPSHOT`?

Comment: Long story short, we want to use the suffix -DEVELOP for snapshots..:)

Comment: Follow the conventions don't try to do different things which will makes things harder...Also your repository manager is not able to clean up the accumulated things in your SNAPSHOT repository because you are technically deploying a release ... Short answer: That is not possible any solution you might find is a hack!!

Comment: I guess you are right. It would've looked nice with our Git flow, but then -SNAPSHOT it is. :)
Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I don't guess here. I know that I'm 100% right, because I know a lot of implementation details of Apache Maven (https://maven.apache.org/team.html). Git flow is in my experience most of the time overengineered.

Comment: Alright, understood! :) Yes, we indeed overthought it a bit.